# Turn off bluetooth by default on start up

Tags: release-freya, startup, bluetooth

When I boot my laptop, Bluetooth is on by default:

[image: bluetooth on upon startup]

Is it possible to set it to instead be off when I start up my laptop?:

[image: bluetooth off]

Comment: Check this out. http://itsfoss.com/turn-off-bluetooth-by-default-in-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 10, accepted):

At @Life's suggestion, I checked out [this post](http://itsfoss.com/turn-off-bluetooth-by-default-in-ubuntu-14-04).  The solution was quite easy and worked like a charm (Thanks, @Life!).  In the terminal, I typed `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` which opened that file in the nano text editor.  Then, above the `exit 0` line, I added `rfkill block bluetooth`, like so:

[image]

After saving and exiting nano (Ctrl-X, Y, Enter), then restarting my computer to test it out, bluetooth is no longer on by default.

Comment: This also works with scrach-text-editor, if someone likes to use Scratch instead

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the Bluetooth service.

```
sudo systemctl stop bluetooth
sudo systemctl disable bluetooth
```