# Cannot update any app

Tags: updates, appcenter, bluetooth

I cannot update any app. 
I click update all or the update for the individual app.. it asks me for authentication and then says waiting for package manager lock and then nothing happens and update cancels.

Also how do i make bluetooth stop switching on automatically every time i switch on PC?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like two questions.

**For the first one**,
try (according to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/498102/how-do-i-unlock-var-lib-dpkg-lock)) removing the locking file with the command in terminal:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

and then running updates manually with the following:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That will update your repositories information and upgrade all the apps needing an update.

**As for the second question,**
try the solution, posted [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/711/turn-off-bluetooth-by-default-on-start-up)!

Answer (score 0):

It is better to run updates from Terminal time to time.
*'sudo apt-get update' and 'sudo apt-get upgrade'* from the error I ran
**sudo dpkg --configure -a** to fix the problem