# Turn off LAN (Ethernet) by default on start up

Tags: startup, ethernet

I noticed that bluetooth and Network settings are restoring to defaults on startup.
I find an old topic how to switch bluetooth off on start up.
[Turn off bluetooth by default on start up](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/711/turn-off-bluetooth-by-default-on-start-up?newreg=6cb6a3a8a2c24dfe951fee87d773b6a2)

Now I want to disable LAN (Ethernet) too. It is enabled after every reboot.
[image]

How someone can help!

Greetings, Max Meier

Comment: Newly installed elementary OS on my HP pavilion, and I can't seem to connect with my home wifi. Do I need drivers ? Or anything like that? I am completely noob to understand the process. Help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
sudo nano /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state
```

And change the line

```
NetworkingEnabled=true
```

to

```
NetworkingEnabled=false
```

On startup, the Ethernet connection will stay disabled.

If you need to enable it back when the computer is on, you just change back the line to `true` and run

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: this will disable wifi too?