# Turn off Bluetooth by default

Tags: wifi, bluetooth

Okay, so I've browsed answers to this question but found none to be satisfying.

The question is: how can I make eOS behave like literally every other OS I know and keep the settings for wireless either on or off after reboot or wake up fro sleep. I tried different solutions offered here but none was really satisfying.

First of all, I'd like to say that I have an issue where I get headaches from Wi-Fi and Bluetooth. It's rare and it's real. Forcing me to handle the setting each time I open my laptop really is a chore.

There has to be some solution to get eOS to behave like every other OS and just stick to whatever settings were chosen. Some people may want to choose to have Bluetooth and Wi-Fi turned off for various other reasons: security, power consumption, etc. Why force a setting to be always on anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried this ?

- check which block is the one for bluetooth

  ```
  rfkill list
  ```
- run this command on the bluetooth block (replace x by your value).

  ```
  rfkill block x
  ```

Comment: So I ran the command 'rfkill list' and it returned this: 
'0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no
6: hci0: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no'; so I tried to proceed with 'rfkill block Bluetooth' but it returned an error. Also tried 'rfkill block hci0' - same result.

Comment: Ah, got it. It was 'rfkill block 6'. Thanks a lot. Hope the devs finally listen to users who want to switch Bluetooth off.

Comment: happy that it worked!
Could you set the response to "accepted" ? So your question disappear from the list of "questions with no upvoted or accepted answers"

Comment: actually i found a more complete answer to your question here : https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/711/turn-off-bluetooth-by-default-on-start-up?rq=1
Had you seen it before posting your question ?

Comment: Yes I saw that answer and I edited rc.local some time ago, but the result was unstable, while your method seems to bring more reliable results.