# Bluetooth start automatically on wake up

Tags: release-hera, bluetooth

I'm on Eos HERA 5.1.3
My bluetooth auto start when i wake up my laptop.
I would like the bluetooth to stay off on wake up, reboot, boot....
But i d'ont want to ban it or kill it everytime...

How to reproduce :
Disable Bluetooth, close the laptop, open the laptop, login, bluetooth is on.

Thanks for you help

Comment: Try this: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/711/turn-off-bluetooth-by-default-on-start-up

Comment: Wouldn't it best suit your need just to turn it off in the system BIOS setup?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the Bluetooth service.

```
sudo systemctl stop bluetooth 

sudo systemctl disable bluetooth
```